# Writing Previously Untranscoded FLAC files to CD

Tags: brasero

I have many FLAC files for writing on CDs. I have been transcoding them to WAV, before writing them to disk. I have since discovered that if I just copy FLAC files into a Brasero project it seems to transcode them automatically. Is this a quality process or just a quick bodge? Would the transcoding be done more precisely if I stick to transcoding them myself beforehand?

Comment: I don't see any way that it could possibly reduce the quality by letting Brasero do it - after all, all brasero is doing is decompressing the FLAC files into lossless audio that goes onto the CD. I don't think that could really go wrong in any way.

Comment: OK, thanks, I won't bother with transcoding them myself and will trust Brasero. I realise that they are both 16 bit integers so it shouldn't be too hard a task for it.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica This would be an appropriate answer to this question